# R - include dataframe in own r package

Tags: r

is it possible to include dataframe in my own function? In R several datasets are included, for example iris.

```
df <-
  data.frame(my = seq(1, 10000))
```

Is it possible to call df same way as iris once my own package is loaded?

Comment: I suggest you read https://r-pkgs.org/data.html, which discusses how to include data in a package.